# load data from page with socket

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-studio-2013

**I chose not to use libcurl since I've already spend too much effort in trying getting it working.**

So I'm new to c++ and don't fully understand everything.

I couldn't get content from example.com/test.php but using test.example.com did work(annoying having to create a sub domain for it though)

Besides that is there a way to get the content only and not the response headers?

My code:

```
string result;
WSADATA wsaData;
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
    cout << "WSAStartup failed.\n";
    system("pause");

}
SOCKET Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
struct hostent *host;
host = gethostbyname("www.example.com");
SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
SockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);
cout << "Connecting...\n";
if (connect(Socket, (SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0){
    cout << "Could not connect";
    system("pause");
}
cout << "Connected.\n";
send(Socket, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: test.example.nl\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n", strlen("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: test.example.nl\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"), 0);
char buffer[10000];
int nDataLength;
while ((nDataLength = recv(Socket, buffer, 10000, 0)) > 0){
    int i = 0;
    while (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r') {
        result += buffer[i];
        i += 1;
    }
}
cout << result;
closesocket(Socket);
WSACleanup();
```

So I found out that the first 160 characters are header related.
To filter out the header I did this:

```
while (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r') {
       if(i > 160) {
            result += buffer[i];
            i += 1;
        }
    }
```

But what if the header isn't the same? For example it's using a different server or something. Or changed php version.

Header I get as response(In case this is interesting for someone)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 13 Feb 2015 20:39:56 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.29
Content-Length: 4
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you make the request the header will change.  You can't just assume it is a fixed number of bytes.  You have to parse the header.  What you need is here:

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt

If you look at page 39, you see that the HTTP header ends with a blank line, so look for the blank line, then the content is below that.  Of course, if this is anything more than an academic exercise, you will probably want to find a library that does this for you.  HTTP is quite complex.

6 Response

After receiving and interpreting a request message, a server responds
   with an HTTP response message.

Here is an excerpt from the spec.  You want "message-body"

```
   Response      = Status-Line               ; Section 6.1
                   *(( general-header        ; Section 4.5
                    | response-header        ; Section 6.2
                    | entity-header ) CRLF)  ; Section 7.1
                   CRLF
                   [ message-body ]          ; Section 7.2
```

Comment: I accepted your answer, and it sorta worked although I'm not quite sure my method is 100% correct.
Since my response header ends with a blank line it means there are 2 CRLF after eachother. So I made it that if that's the case it starts saving the info giving me the content only.